# d3 v4 force layout with drag,zoom and edge label

Tags: d3.js, hyperlink, label, edge-list

I am trying implement labels on links in d3 v4 force layout. Although I am following code from a [b.lock](http://bl.ocks.org/fancellu/2c782394602a93921faff74e594d1bb1), I face difficulty to achieve the labelling. I am probably missing some basics at svg.selectAll and svg.append .

```
svg = d3.select("#svgdiv").append('svg').attr('width',width).attr('height',height).style("border","1px solid black"),
width = +svg.attr("width"),
height = +svg.attr("height");


svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("fill", "black")
    .style("pointer-events", "all")
    .call(d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 4])
      .on("zoom", zoomed));

g=svg.append("g");

function zoomed() {
  g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}

link = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.edge)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); })
    .attr("id",function(d,i) {return 'edge'+i});


node = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.node)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", radius)
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })   
    .on("click", mouseClick(.2))
    .on("dblclick", mouseDblClick)
    .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended));
```

Till here, the code is ok. But when I add the following code for labelling, it stops working.

```
edgepaths =svg.selectAll(".edgepath")
.data(graph.edge)
.enter()
.append('path')
.attr({'d': function(d) {return 'M '+d.source.x+' '+d.source.y+' L '+ d.target.x +' '+d.target.y},
       'class':'edgepath',
       'fill-opacity':0,
       'stroke-opacity':0,
       'fill':'green',
       'stroke':'yellow',
       'id':function(d,i) {return 'edgepath'+i}})
.style("pointer-events", "none");

edgelabels =svg.selectAll(".edgelabel")
.data(graph.edge)
.enter()
.append('text')
.style("pointer-events", "none")
.attr({'class':'edgelabel',
   'id':function(d,i){return 'edgelabel'+i},
   'dx':80,
   'dy':0,
   'font-size':10,
   'fill':'white'});

edgelabels.append('textPath')
.attr('xlink:href',function(d,i) {return '#edgepath'+i})
.style("pointer-events", "none")
.text(function(d,i){return 'label '+i});

function ticked() {   
    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x;})
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y;})     
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });


    edgepaths.attr('d', function(d) { 
        var path='M '+d.source.x+' '+d.source.y+' L '+ d.target.x +' '+d.target.y;
        //console.log(d)
        return path});



    edgelabels.attr('transform',function(d,i){
        if (d.target.x<d.source.x){
            bbox = this.getBBox();
            rx = bbox.x+bbox.width/2;
            ry = bbox.y+bbox.height/2;
            return 'rotate(180 '+rx+' '+ry+')';
        }
        else {
            return 'rotate(0)';
        }
    });
}
```

please help.
thank you.

JSON data.

```
{
"edge":[ 
{"source":"source1","target":"target1","value":"1"},
{"source":"source2","target":"target2","value":"0"},
.
.
],
"node":[
{"group":0,"id":"source1"},
{"group":3,"id":"source2"},
.
.
]
}
```

Comment: any specific errors ?

Comment: No errors. The graph shows. but only one node with misplaced x,y co-ords.

Comment: are you using the same graph.json from b.lock? and its not clear what is your expected outcome

Comment: My json is custom. I will update it here.

Comment: You have a typo: `.attr({'class':'edgelabel', etc...` should be `.attrs({'class':'edgelabel',`. It's `attrs`, not `attr`.

Comment: yes. that was it. thank you.